# How to show that $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^4} x^Tx$ subject to $x^TAx \geq 1$ has a global minimizer?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, symmetric-matrices

Consider the following problem:

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^4} x^Tx$$

over $C=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x^TAx \geq 1\}$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$ is a symmetric matrix with two distinct positive eigenvalues and other eigenvalues of $A$ are nonpositive.

How to show that this problem has a global minimizer?

I need to show that there exist $x_*$ in $C$ for which I have
$$
x_*^Tx_* \leq x^Tx \,\,\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^4 
$$

or to come up with something like the following
$$
\|x\|^2= \|x_*\|^2 + \alpha  \,\,\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^4 ,\,\,\, 0<\alpha \in \mathbb{R}
$$

My try:

$A$ is symmetric, so it can be written as $A=u \Lambda u^T$. Hence,

$$
x^TAx=x^Tu \Lambda u^Tx \geq 1
$$

So

$$
z^T \Lambda z \geq 1
$$
where $u^Tx=z \in \mathbb{R}^4$. So the optimization problem would be

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^4} z^Tz$$
over $z^T \Lambda z \geq 1$.
How can we proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose some $R>0$ such that $B_R:=\{z^Tz\le R^2\}$ has nonempty intersection with $F:=\{z^TAz\ge1\}$. Now $B_R\cap F$ is compact and has a global minimiser, which must also be a global minimiser for the original problem (why?).

Hint: minimisation over $F$ is minimisation over $(F\cap B_R)\cup (F\cap\text{cl}( B_R^c))$. But minimising $\|x\|^2$ over $(F\cap B_R)$ must yield an optimal value that is smaller than or equal to minimising over $(F\cap\text{cl}( B_R^c))$.

Comment: I do not know, can you explain it to me?

Comment: @Sepide because any objective value outside B_R is surely >= inside B_R.

Comment: Is the ball contained in the feasible set? If so, for the points that are not in the ball but are in the feasible set, how we know that we cannot find a point that has a value less that what we get from the point that is inside the ball?

Comment: @Sepide the ball doesn't have to be contained in the feasible region because we only care about the *intersection* of the ball and the feasibility. Please see my edit.